# I've a PowerShell Script that checks the ACM status for 1 AWS account. How can I scale it for multiple AWS accounts without using the IAM keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, automation, cloud, devops

The current script checks the status of each AWS ACM certificate in every region and if ACM is expired, it invokes auto renewal for eligible ACM certs. Can you advise how I can scale this script to work the same way for multiple AWS accounts please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/), you can create a user in one of the linked accounts and give it the appropriate access to all the accounts in the organization. Here the brief description from the service page:

> AWS Organizations helps you centrally govern your environment as you grow and scale your workloads on AWS. Whether you are a growing startup or a large enterprise, Organizations helps you to centrally manage billing; control access, compliance, and security; and share resources across your AWS accounts.

In your case, you can have one IAM user or Role with access to the appropriate ACM action of all the linked accounts as well as the access to list all the accounts in the organization. With that you can simply loop through all the accounts and perform the check.

Comment: @Rakesh, if the answer did indeed address your question, do you mind accepting it. That way, others who stumble upon this can easily find the solution. Cheers.